# more p-value decimals in output for Waldtest (eRm)?

Tags: r

I'm calculating Wald tests (with the R package `eRm`) and tried without success to get more than 3 p-value decimals (I do need them because of alpha-correction)

Does someone have an idea, how in this specific output I can get more decimals?

Changing `digits = ..`, in `print()` didn't work.

```
library("eRm")
res <- RM(ds_matrix)
wald <- Waldtest(res, splitcr = splitage)     
print(wald)   
## Wald test on item level (z-values):
##           z-statistic p-value
## beta I01        1.489   0.136
## beta I02        0.908   0.364
## beta I03        0.402   0.688
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
w <- Waldtest(res, splitcr = splitage)
pvals <- w$coef.table[,"p-value"]
print(pvals,digits=22)
```

Results:

```
                 beta I1                  beta I2                  beta I5 
0.5019397827755713858977 0.6252106345771608619799 0.6384882841798422692392 
                 beta I6 
0.7424853136244984330716
```